# Connecting to localhost server results in non-localhost client address

Tags: networking

I have a laptop with a somewhat weird networking setup: in order to be able to forward any Internet access from my VMs and containers to whatever default route my laptop happens to have (which could be `wlan0`, `eth0` or `ppp0`), I've set the usual `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and the following in my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lxcbr0

iface lxcbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.56.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
        # XXX: no --out-interface
        up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
        down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

I use NetworkManager to obtain my Internet connection. So far, this worked normally, until I tried to launch `fossil ui` and it turned out that connecting to `127.0.0.1` in this setup results in client address being from a different subnet.

For example, the following Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.020;
use IO::Socket::INET;
say IO::Socket::INET::->new(
        Proto=>"tcp", Listen=>0,
        LocalAddr=>"127.0.0.1:8080",
        ReuseAddr=>1, ReusePort=>1,
)->accept->peerhost;
```

would normally print `127.0.0.1` if I use `nc 127.0.0.1 8080` to connect to it (and it does so on my other machines), but on this laptop it prints `192.168.1.11` (which is indeed the address of `wlan0` where my current default route resides).

I tried to add a special route to `127.0.0.0/8` via `lo`, but it didn't change anything.

How do I make localhost connections behave like they're actually from localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `! --out-interface lo` to the NAT firewall rule did the trick: now `lo` access is governed by the usual laws and is not subject to any masquerading (as it shouldn't).